# Highlight a child account if headquarters not working in LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

Below is the code for child LWC component which shows child account in iteration. This has to be highlighted by changing account name color and background. I am using below code:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildItem extends LightningElement {
    @api childAccount;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.childAccount.styleClass = this.childAccount.Headquarter__c ? 'highlight' : '';
    }
}
```

All the information is showing correctly but I don't see the class added.
What am I missing?

Comment: can you add the markup where you have referenced this child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api` variables are not allowed to be modified when parent is setting that variable during init. You can use below instead:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildItem extends LightningElement {
    @api childAccount;
    @track childAccountPrivate;


    connectedCallback() {
        this.childAccountPrivate = this.childAccount;
        this.childAccountPrivate.styleClass = this.childAccountPrivate.Headquarter__c ? 'highlight' : '';
    }
}
```